# how does the "Favourate" button in StackOverFlow works?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am creating a forum for my website. i would like to know how does the "This is your favourate question" button in StackOverFlow webpage(ie this website) works?

i am using django.

i created models such as:

### models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    topic=models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    question=models.TextField()
    tags=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)


class Favourites(models.Model):
    '''
    Does this your Favourite Question'''
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    favourite=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question=models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

also i would like to know how to create view to get total favourites for a particular question and also any other modified models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably don't need the 'favourite' field. You can assume that, if there is entry in your table for a given question, related to a given user, that question is that users favorite.
2. You'll need to create a view which will take a question id, and mark it as the currently logged in user's favorite:

   ```
   def mark_as_favorite(request, question_id, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
           question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
           favorite = Favourite.objects.create(user=request.user, question=question)
           return HttpResponse("Marked")
       else:
           return HttpResponseForbidden("User is not logged in")
   ```
3. Finding the total favorites for a given question is easy:

   ```
   def question(request, quesiton_id, *args, **kwargs):
       question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
       favorites = Favourites.objects.filter(question=question)
       favorites_count = favorites.count()
       return render_to_response('template', {'question':questions, 'favorites_count':favorites_count}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   ```

Comment: thanks for your answer. ...you mean i just need the fields (user=models.ForeignKey(User),question=models.ForeignKey(Question)).....so how will i know whether the user is starred a question or not when he viewing questions? for that does i need to check whether the model Favorite contains fields(user ,question) exist or  not? Thanks for the Views That is very help. I will surely vote up for that.

Comment: Just checking that a Favorite with the appropriate user and question set is enough. The boolean is redundant.

Comment: does i need to delete the entire field if the user deselect favourate

Answer (score 1):

i just edited jack shedd's answer

```
def mark_as_favorite(request, question_id, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        fav, created = Favourite.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, question=question)
        if created:
            return HttpResponse("Marked")
        else:
            fav.delete()
            return HttpResponse("Un Marked")

    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("User is not logged in")
```